# How to prove the space $H$ is Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let
$$H=\{\text{$f$:$f$ and its derivative are absolutely continuous and squared integrable in $\mathbb{R}$}\}.$$ The norm is
$$\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f'(t)|^2\mathrm{d}t}$$
Prove $H$ is a Banach space.

1. I only know the Cauchy sequence in $H$ is convergent to a function in $L^2$, and use this property I get two functions $f$ and $f'$.
2. I thought $f$ and $f'$ can be replaced by continuous functions before, but now I realize that I don't know how to prove this point. If this is true, the remaining is verify $f'$ is the derivative of $f$.

I've know that the Sobolev embedding theorem can be used to fix the point 2. I wish to get a solution that beginner can understand because I saw this problem at the beginning of some functional analysis book.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please also write down what you have done yourself to answer this question. This will allow others to help you in a better way. In this particular case, I am sure that you can prove some of the things required of $H$ to be Banach. For example, can you prove $H$ is a vector space?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: You might want to look up what a [Sobolev space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#One-dimensional_case) is (particularly the $W^{1,2}$ space in the notation of Wikipedia).

Comment: I've seen an answer about this question, which relates to Sobolev space and embeding theorem. I'm just learning  functional analysis and this is an exercise in the section of metric space at the beginning of a functional analysis book. So I want to know if this question has some "elementary" answer.